# htaccess Redirect Subfolder only (to lower case)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I've been searching and there are so many different examples here, but can't seem to find exactly what I need.  Shared Environ...no access to httpd.conf

`www.mysite.com/SuBfolder1/FiLe1.php`  (camel case)
`www.mysite.com/SUBFOLDER2/FILE2.php`  (all caps)
`www.mysite.com/subfoldeR3/filE3.php`  (one cap)
... and so on with many different subfolders...

In any of these instances...I'd want to redirect to the lowercase version of 'subfolderx'.  But not affect anything below those folders.  Some files under these folders may have caps too so I don't want the entire URL converted to lowercase.

Desired outcome:

`www.mysite.com/subfolder1/FiLe1.php`
`www.mysite.com/subfolder2/FILE2.php`
`www.mysite.com/subfolder3/filE3.php`
and so on for any subfolder

I think I could do something like this, but trying to do dynamic.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SuBfolder1`
`RewriteRule (.*) /subfolder1/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Shared environment...so no access for RewriteMap or whatever.  Dynamically would be better, but I can do a list of folders...just requires modification anytime a folder is added.

Comment: Without RewriteMap, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: No common traits.  Subfolders can be 'abcd', 'alpha', 'sun', 'pc'...basically anything.  What I'm trying to do is just have the URL subfolder be redirected to lowercase.  So that if someone types something else (All caps would be most common)...then we can redirect to the proper folder...since Linux boxes are case sensitive when it comes to folder names.  The catch is...I can't convert everything because some file names may actually be Capitalized.

Comment: Anything after the 'Subfolder' position in my URLs...it can stay the same regarding case.  I'm not going to correct for everything.  I just want that first folder in the path to be directed correctly to the lowercase version should a user enter ALL CAPS or something for that folder name.

Comment: @Prix Gets a little more complicated.  There is a default subfolder. So, if just type `www.mysite.com` it gets redirected to `www.mysite.com\default`.  So, in my htaccess file at the root I have to first check if `!^/subfolder1`...redirect to /default.  Maybe not worth the time to fix this. lol  So, I don't do that manually...what'd be the best way if I write code for each folder.  I put some possible code in the main question above.  Unless an easier RegEx way...probably wouldn't be checking for anything other than ALL CAPS to redirect.